# Find files that has write permission for current user

Tags: bash, file, find

I need to find files in a directory which has "write" permissions for the current user.

I tried using `find` like below:

```
find $DIR -type f -user $(whoami) -perm -u+w
```

But the above `find` looks for file owned by `$(whoami)`.

The files that i am looking for may not be owned by `$(whoami)` but still has permissions (for eg., 666 permission)

I also tried below (sorry if it looks stupid):

```
find $DIR -type f -exec test -w {} \;
```

Comment: This could be so simple if only `find` would offer the option `-writeable` in addition to the already existing operations `-executable` and `-readable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second command is correct, you just have to print the paths. Usually `-print` doesn't have to be mentioned, but with a few options like `-exec` you have to explicitly specify that you want to print the found paths.

```
find "$DIR" -type f -exec test -w {} \; -print
```

You may wonder: »**Why does this print only writeable files?**«

`find` uses *short-circuit evaluation* – the next option is only evaluated if the preceding option succeeded.
**Example:** In the command `find -type f -user USER` the check `-user USER` will only be performed on files, not on directories as `-type f` fails for directories.

The `-exec cmd` option also acts as a check – the exit status of `cmd` will be used to determine whether the check passed or not.
**Example:** `find -exec false \; -user USER` won't ever perform the check `-user USER` since the program `false` never succeeds.

In your case that means that `-print` will only be executed if `test -w` succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach seems to be on the right track; you just forgot to print the filename.

You could make a script

```
#!/bin/sh
test -w "$1" && echo "$1"
```

and then use `-exec` on this script.

UPDATE: If you don't like the idea of having a separate script, you can put it also into one line:

```
find $DIR -type f -exec bash -c 'test -w "$1" && echo "$1"' x {} \;
```

The lone *x* just serves as a placeholder, because this is what bash sees as $0, and you want to assign the current file to $1. Another possibility would be

```
find $DIR -type f -exec bash -c 'test -w "$0" && echo "$0"' {} \;
```

but for me, this looks less clear and like a misuse of $0.